# Compare result with previous and do X if difference Y

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I'm trying to echo an array where I want to compare the actual number with the previous one. The result is in %. If the % difference between the current and the previous is more than 10% I want to color the font red.

Unfortunately my whole result will be red and I don't know where I can place the 10% difference.

```
<?php
#Difference_Query
$Difference_Query = "SELECT (SUM(current) * 100) / ((SUM(cw_1) + SUM(cw_2)) / 2) AS Diff FROM table GROUP BY time";
$Difference = mysqli_query($connect, $Difference_Query);

$previous = 0;
foreach($Difference as $result) {
    if($previous > $result['Diff']) {
        echo "<font color = 'red'>".number_format($result['Diff'], 2, ",", ".")."%"."</font>"."<br>";
    } else {
        echo number_format($result['Diff'], 2, ",", "."), "%", "<br>";
    }
    $previous = $result['Diff'];
}?>
```

Current visual:

```
159,09% (red)
196,17% (red)
196,67% (red)
188,56%
188,41%
181,55%
178,15%
175,74%
183,03% (red)
193,31% (red)
224,28% (red)
230,28% (red)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different things that doesn't seem the proper way to do, or even incorrect in your code. Try with this and don't hesitate to comment if you have trouble, i'll try to update.

_Usually the best way to extract rows from a query result is to use the functions specifically made for that, in your case for example `mysqli_fetch_assoc` (which will use the alias or column name as key for your array)

_`implode` is useless now in theory if `$result['Diff']` is an int (you actually want an int), and will even throw an error

_it's not very clear if you want that the difference between previous and current is 10, or 10% of current. The example shows the first one

```
 <?php
$Difference_Query = "SELECT (SUM(current) * 100) / ((SUM(cw_1) + SUM(cw_2)) / 2) AS Diff FROM table GROUP BY time";
$Difference = mysqli_query($connect, $Difference_Query);

$previous = 0;
while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Difference)) {
    //abs is in case results are not in ascending order; this if will test if current is more than previous+10 or less than previous-10
    if(abs($result['Diff'] - $previous) > 10) {
        echo "<font color = 'red'>".number_format($result['Diff'], 2, ",", ".")."%"."</font>"."<br>";
    } else {
         echo number_format($result['Diff'], 2, ",", "."), "%", "<br>";
    }
    $previous = $result['Diff'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for @FedericoklezCulloca for asking you all these questions that clarified the problem ;) good coding all

Comment: Many thanks to him as well. Now let us all enjoy some football. Germany is playing. Have a nice day you two!